# Sonar - Python plugin rules, what tools it uses behind?

Tags: python, plugins, sonarqube, static-analysis

I am setting sonar to analyze a python module and I came up with a doubt about the metrics it generates, 
maybe a Sonar team member could help me to understand.
What tools and 3rd parties tools Sonar uses to calculate the static analysis in Python plugin?
I mean, for example for java I know that Sonar rules are a pool of metrics such as Findbugs, checkstyle, PMD, etc,
so, for python, what does it use? Does it use pylint, flake8, radon, other? Or does it use a pool of own Sonar rules? Based on which experience?

Thanks a lot for the help.
I need to know this, because I am proposing to start using Sonar for static and test metrics in our team.

Ragards.

Answer (score 3):

Some custom rules are implemented in Java, just take a look at [GitHub](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-python/blob/master/python-checks/src/main/java/org/sonar/python/checks/).

As you supposed, they also use Pylint to [analyse files](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-python/blob/master/sonar-python-plugin/src/main/java/org/sonar/plugins/python/pylint/PylintIssuesAnalyzer.java).

> By default the Python Plugin will execute for you the pylint command
>   (the path to this command can be tuned using sonar.python.pylint
>   property)

You can prepare Pylint report to analyse [on your own](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Pylint+Report).

Another interesting thing is code coverage:

> The Python Plugin does not generate its own test coverage report, but
>   re-uses the one generated by the Coverage Tool or Nose.

Other things like complexity are handled and calculated by their java code.